# 400 Error - Missing destination email with x-smtpapi

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I'm using the latest version of these api :
- Sendgrid v6.3.4
- SendGrid.SmtpApi v1.3.1

The description of the API is here : https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

I try to follow this example : https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-csharp but it fail everytime I try it.

My goal is to use substitution with few emails without a recipient see another recipients in "to" field. I try with BCC, but it doestn' work.

There is my code (almost a copy of the example) :

```
    SendGridMessage mailMsg = new SendGridMessage();

    mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(mail.Sender);

    SendGrid.SmtpApi.Header header = new SendGrid.SmtpApi.Header();
    header.SetTo(mail.Receivers);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<String>> tag in mail.Tags)
        header.AddSubstitution(tag.Key, tag.Value);

    foreach (String s in mail.BCC)
        mailMsg.AddBcc(s);

    foreach (String s in mail.CC)
        mailMsg.AddCc(s);

    mailMsg.Subject = mail.Subject;

    mailMsg.Html = mail.Content;

    foreach (String s in mail.Attachments)
        mailMsg.AddAttachment(s);

    mailMsg.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", header.JsonString());

    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(sLogin, sPassword);
    var transportWeb = new Web(credential);

    try
    {
        transportWeb.DeliverAsync(mailMsg).Wait();
    }
```

There is how the email is send by the API :

```
POST https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.xml HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: sendgrid/6.3.4.0;csharp
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="2407d110-de4b-4a28-9beb-1da71362d11d"
Host: api.sendgrid.com
Content-Length: 1253
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

--2407d110-de4b-4a28-9beb-1da71362d11d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=headers

{"X-SMTPAPI":"{\"to\" : [\"gregory.wizard@toto.fr\", \"baptiste.butterfly@toto.fr\", \"baptx75@toto.com\", \"tixounet@toto.fr\"],\"sub\" : {\"**coucou**\" : [\"Gregory\", \"Baptiste\", \"BaptX\", \"Tixounet\"],\"**toto**\" : [\"loup\", \"chou\", \"bisou\", \"caillou\"]}}"}
--2407d110-de4b-4a28-9beb-1da71362d11d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=from

utile@toto.fr
--2407d110-de4b-4a28-9beb-1da71362d11d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=subject

Test Sendgrid
--2407d110-de4b-4a28-9beb-1da71362d11d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=html

Salut **coucou**, j'espère que tu vas bien. Je t'aime mon petit **toto** ! Bisous
--2407d110-de4b-4a28-9beb-1da71362d11d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=api_user

xxxxxxxxxx
--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=api_key

xxxxxxxxxx
--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And there is the answer of Sendgrid :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 15:35:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 136
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: DENY

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><result><message>error</message><errors><error>Missing destination email</error></errors></result>
```

I don't understand. I follow the API example and it doesn't work.

Comment: What mail server are you using?  The sample code uses client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; which means that the user is not using an Outlook Account.    You are missing this statement.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question ? I'm using the Sendgrid Web Library. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Comment: I understand the question.  Looking at the example at the website you are missing a critical statement.  You are also missing the "To" address from the sample code which is the error message you posted.  The email will not work without both fixes.

Comment: If I use the "To", each receiver will see all the email address

Comment: An email MUST have a "to" address.  To send email blind then you must call the api for each receiver with a different "To" address.

Comment: It is stupid. What the goal of substitution if you have to call api mail per mail in order to keep anonymous ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111699/discussion-between-baptx-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works now ! In fact, you have to put twice email recipients. The first time in the "To" property, the second time in the feader.

Here is my code :

```
private void SendMailToSendGrid(Mail mail)
{
    SendGridMessage mailMsg = new SendGridMessage();

    mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(mail.Sender);

    SendGrid.SmtpApi.Header header = new SendGrid.SmtpApi.Header();
    header.SetTo(mail.Receivers);

    mailMsg.AddTo(mail.Receivers);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<String>> tag in mail.Tags)
        header.AddSubstitution(tag.Key, tag.Value);

    foreach (String s in mail.BCC)
        mailMsg.AddBcc(s);

    foreach (String s in mail.CC)
        mailMsg.AddCc(s);

    mailMsg.Subject = mail.Subject;

    mailMsg.Html = mail.Content;

    foreach (String s in mail.Attachments)
        mailMsg.AddAttachment(s);

    mailMsg.Headers.Add("x-smtpapi", header.JsonString());

    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(sLogin, sPassword);
    var transportWeb = new Web(credential);

    try
    {
        transportWeb.DeliverAsync(mailMsg).Wait();
    }
    catch (InvalidApiRequestException ex)
    {
        var errDetail = new StringBuilder();

        errDetail.Append("ResponseStatusCode: " + ex.ResponseStatusCode + ". ");

        for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count(); i++)
        {
            errDetail.Append(" -- Error # " + i.ToString() + " : " + ex.Errors[i]);
        }

        throw new ApplicationException(errDetail.ToString(), ex);
    }

}
```